# Bootstrap tabs don't function properly inside a modal

Tags: javascript, django, bootstrap-4

I am using Django and Bootstrap to display nav-tabs inside a modal, shown when a button is clicked. The issue is that when a tab is clicked its content is not shown.

Below you can see a simple example:

```
{% load static %}
{% load rest_framework %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="{% static "myapp/js/modal.js" %}"></script>
</head>

<body>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="show-modal">Show modal</button>

{% include "myapp/modal_test.html" %}
</body
```

My js script:

```
$(document).on("click", "#show-modal", function () {
    $("#exampleModalCenter").modal('show');
});
```

The modal code I am talking about:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

            <ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
              <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">0</div>
              <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">1</div>
              <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">2</div>
            </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I click the button, the modal is shown as expected. Although, clicking on other tabs does not show their content.

Using the nav-tabs in a separate page works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, commenting out [Jasny Bootstrap](http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/), seems to have solved my problem.

```
<script src="{% static "bets/js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js" %}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{%  static "bets/css/jasny-bootstrap.min.css" %}"/>
```